# How can I decompress a Zip file using (just) Ruby 1.9.3?

Tags: ruby, zip

I need to decompress a Zip file that contains several folders using just Ruby and save it to a folder. No system calls.

I use Ruby 1.9.3.

How can I do that?

Comment: Google 'ruby decompress file' and use the first result.

Comment: @MichaelDurrant: Rubyzip is not compatible with ruby 1.9.3

Comment: Just to say.. this IS the first google result for 'ruby decompress file'. That's how I got here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check these:

http://rubygems.org/gems/zip

[What zip library works well with Ruby 1.9.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5892415/what-zip-library-works-well-with-ruby-1-9-2)

[Compression libraries for Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845348/compression-libraries-for-ruby)